# How does R handle ambiguous column names?

Tags: r

Recently, I came across a strange behavior of R that I wanted to better understand.

Let us assume the following two examples:

```
Example 1:

ebit.2018_base <- c(1,2,3,5,7,3,2)
ebit.2017_base <- c(1,2,3,5,7,3,2)
ebit <- data.frame(ebit.2018_base, ebit.2017_base)

ebit$test <- ebit$ebit.2018 * 5
```

R can compute with this column name, even though it does not exactly match.

```
Example 2

ebit.2018_base <- c(1,2,3,5,7,3,2)
ebit.2018_notbase <- c(1,2,3,5,7,3,2)
ebit.2017_base <- c(1,2,3,5,7,3,2)
ebit <- data.frame(ebit.2018_base, ebit.2018_notbase, ebit.2017_base)

ebit$test <- ebit$ebit.2018 * 5
```

This does not work.

**My hypothesis:** in the first example, R can clearly understand that I refer to the column `ebit.2018_base` by using the term `ebit.2018`. In the second example, it is ambiguous because there are two columns starting with `ebit.2018`.

Is this correct? Sorry if this is common knowledge or has been previously addressed, I just want to be sure I understand the logic behind correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As expressed in the answer, the `$` operator allows for partial matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right!

From the documentation of Extract (which you can access through: `?"$"` or `?Extract`):

> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference
>   is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is
>   equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching
>   behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

Because $ allows partial matching, your first case works. But in the second case, it doesn't resolve a single column and therefore thinks you're asking for a non-existing one; hence the error.

Comment: See also: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors